# Create a change log (timestamped) in Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, text-editor, kate, timestamp

I want to keep a change log of things I do in Kubuntu - in other words if I tweak some setting I want to make a written record of it so I can roll back if I screw up.

What's the best way to do this?  I know that in Windows notepad I could add ".LOG" to the start of a file and it would insert the time and date after each entry.  I see that Kubuntu's Kate editor has a "Changelog" mode, but could I use this for what I want to do?

Comment: User settings (background, icons, network etc), or system settings (grub config, etc)?

Comment: More keeping track of things I've installed, either with sudo apt-get or package manager, and also changes I've made to configuration files etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a script. Suppose that your log file is `$HOME/etc/mylogfile.txt`.

Then save this script with a useful name in your $HOME/bin folder, for example `addtolog`, and make it executable:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
logfile=$HOME/etc/mylogfile.txt
{ 
  echo                   #blank line 
  echo -n "Entry on "    #echo -n output the text without a new line
  date                   #current date 
  echo                   #other blank line
} >> $logfile            #append output of {...} to $logfile
gvim + "$logfile"        #change with your preferred editor. The + tells gvim to 
                         #open the file and put the cursor at the end
exit
```

Then you can use the command `addtolog` and start writing. The nice thing is that you can heavily customize this in the way you want --- change text, date format, whatever.

The editor `Kate` seems to have a `-l` option to go to a line, but not a "go to the end of file" command; but this is solved with (substitute the `gvim` line with this one)

```
kate -l $(wc -l "$logfile") "$logfile" &> /dev/null
```

`wc -l file` returns the number of lines in the file `file`; we use the `$()` bash command substitution here. The `&> /dev/null` here is to shut `Kate` a bit --- in a non-KDE environment like mine is otherwise incredibly verbose.

If you want to launch it from the desktop, simply prepare a `.desktop` file for it (you can find tens of answers on how to do that here).

Comment: Rmano that seems to work well with my chosen editor (Kate), but I must be missing something because the first time I run the script, Kate opens and timestamps, and the cursor is in the right place, but if I save, close and re run the script, the next timestamp is at the BOTTOM but the cursor is at the TOP.

Comment: You have to find which command line option opens Kate and jump to the end of the file. In gvim is the `+`. I do not use Kate...

Comment: Found a solution for you!. Please mark the answer as answered if this solves your problem, so that other users can find it!